# Getting lightning stylesheets in salesforce1 page?

Tags: lightning, salesforce1-app, html, slds

I am migrating a VF page to look better and be usable in the Salesforce1 app on mobile devices.

I have been pulling in lightning stylesheets by including

```
<apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />
```

In my page head. However, in Salesforce1, this is not pulling in lightning stylesheets. My slds-button slds-button--neutral elements are all messed up. My text is different looking, and I lost my loading spinner, which I created like so:

```
<div id="loadingSpinner" class="slds-spinner_container" style="display: block; z-index: 13000;">
        <div role="status" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner--medium slds-spinner--brand">
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have `<body class="slds-scope">` wrapping everything.

I don't really have buttons showing up on my mobile page, so I can get around them being enormous because they don't have proper stylesheets. But I do really need my loading spinner back...

Has anyone encountered such a thing? Or is there something different I have to do to bring in lightning stylesheets in Salesforce1?

P.S. I also include `<apex:slds />` in my Visualforce page head.

Comment: Have you tried setting `lightningStylesheets="true"` attribute for `apex:page` tag. Its winter'18 feature mentioned in [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_vf_lightningstylesheets.htm), it works for in browser when we view page in Lightning UI; not exactly sure about Salesforce1. Lightning out is totally different concept to expose a lightning component outside salesforce lightning container and its not for styling.

Comment: Unfortunately adding lightningStylesheets="true" didn't do anything. I tried commenting out <apex:slds /> while having lightningStylesheets="true" in case there may be some conflict for whatever reason, still nothing.